# Chrome - Unable to read sessions for cross domain requests

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

First I'm apologizing if the title of my question is not correct or not clear. But I will explain my issue below.

Lets say I have a web application called `mywebapp.com` and i have a page `loadjs.php`. Here, I have some JS code and the content time of the file is `application/javascript`.

### loadjs.php (mywebapp.com)

```
header("content-type: application/javascript")
echo "alert('some message here');";
```

I will use the above file in a page (`index.html`) of another web app as a javascript source. let's say that it is `anotherwebapp.com`.

### `index.html` (anotherwebapp.com)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//mywebapp.com/loadjs.php"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some contenct here..
    </body>
</html>
```

When this runs, there should be javascript alert as I wrote in `loadjs.php` (mywebapp.com).

### Note:

The above is working without any issue.

### My Issue:

Lets assume now I want to display this alret only for the logged in users for mywebapp.com. That means, when a user who has logged in already in mywebapp.com will see an alert when they visit anotherwebapp.com in the same browser.

So my loadjs.php file will be as below.

```
header("content-type: application/javascript")
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true)
    echo "alert('some message here');";
```

Let's assume that `$_SESSION['logged_in']` has been already set after the user login.

It was working properly in Firefox and and IE. But..

### Chrome browser was not working properly.

So the reason is, chrome cannot read the session value as other browsers do.

### Is there any special reason for this and is there any way to overcome this?

(Please note that the above coding sample is just an example to explain my issue.)

Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

Session is handled server-side, so this is not a Chrome problem.

It could be a caching problem: the js file is first loaded without the alert (because the user is not logged in) but when the user logs in the js is loaded from cache and not downloaded again causing the alert to not display.

Chrome has a pretty "aggressive" caching policy, had some troubles like this before.

You should try to add a timestamp or some kind of dummy value like so that on every page reload you force the javascript file to be downloaded again

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//mywebapp.com/loadjs.php?dummy=
     <? echo time() ?>"></script>
</head>
```

I haven't been using php for quite some time so this might not work but you should get the idea

Comment: Hi @Critic47, I understood the idea of caching. But.. (in not logged in scenario), when I changed the alert message of the loadjs.file and refresh the index.html page, it displayed the updated message. that means, caching is not the issue here. Anyway, thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: Well that could be because in this case the file is saved (so it's basically a different file) and it gets downloaded again. Dunno, it's a strange issue, you should probably just try :P

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting issue. I do not have an environment to test this right now, but the first thing I would like to do is to print the `$_SESSION['logged_in']` while making a request using FF, then Chrome. If for Chrome the value is false, you have to debug why. It could be a crossdomain policy issue.

You can take a look at this: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access%5fcontrol%5fCORS)

Maybe you need to send this header from mywebapp.com:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://anotherwebapp.com`

Please also share if the js console of Chrome shows any error.

Update: the issue was due to chrome browser cookie settings dialed in to be restrictive. Go to `chrome://settings/content` and make sure `Block third-party cookies and site data` is not checked.

Comment: Hi @Joy Dutta, I had already tried it by setting header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") which allows all cross domains. There is no js error also. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

**The reason for your problem is:**
The session ID is sent as a cookie, and since your request is cross-domain, it's considered a third party cookie by the browser. Several browsers will block third-party cookies.

**The solution to your problem is**
Generate the session ID on the client (in the browser), use Javascript sessionStorage to store the session ID then send the session ID with each request to the server.

Details in this article (related to XMLHttpRequest, but your issue is essentially the same): [Javascript Cross-Domain Request With Session](https://404it.no/en/blog/javascript_cross-domain_request_with_session)